# Have I missed a tag with this stripe mesh Gradient?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to recreate the stripe animated Gradient mesh using whatamesh.vercel.app I've created the JS file and pasted all the gist code into it, and I've added all the code in the correct areas but it still wont work. I'm not sure what I'm missing?

I've found other site showing Codepens with similar results but even they say that whatamesh is cleaner. so Ive come back to it after trying the alternatives they've shown which also didn't work.

I've had to paste the link to the Gradient.js file provided by whatamesh as there's a character limit.

```js
https://gist.github.com/jordienr/64bcf75f8b08641f205bd6a1a0d4ce1d
```

```css
#gradient-canvas {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    --gradient-color-1: #ebebeb; 
    --gradient-color-2: #ffb5af; 
    --gradient-color-3: #ebebeb;  
    --gradient-color-4: #ebebeb;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>hello world</h1>
            <canvas id="gradient-canvas" data-transition-in></canvas>    
        </div>
        


        <script src="./Gradient.js"> 
        
            import { Gradient } from './Gradient.js'

            // Create your instance
            const gradient = new Gradient()
        
            // Call `initGradient` with the selector to your canvas
            gradient.initGradient('#gradient-canvas')
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey ıf u still dont find out the answer ı can help u. Just ignore the "gradient.js" step and delete "export { Gradient }" from the github code. Copy the rest of the code and paste it in html . After that paste other codes
"const gradient = new Gradient()"
"gradient.initGradient('#gradient-canvas')"
below the last pasted code. its working 100%.